# Project Euler #4 with python. What;s wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to do project euler problem 4 using python. The problem statement goes like this:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

I wrote down a solution for it:

```
s=0
x=100
y=100
list=[]
z=x*y
def palindrome():
    while z>=1:
        s=s*10+z%10
        z=z/10
        if z==s:
            list.append(z)
while x<=999:
    while y<=999:
        palindrome()
        y=y+1
    x=x+1
    y=100
print list
```

It ended up giving an error along the lines of 'z referenced beyond assignment'.

I searched for a solution to this error before finally deciding to use the syntax 'global' to bypass this error.

```
s=0
x=100
y=100
list=[]
z=x*y
def palindrome():
    global z
    global s
    global x
    global y
    global list
    while z>=1:
        s=s*10+z%10
        z=z/10
        if z==s:
            list.append(z)
while x<=999:
    while y<=999:
        palindrome()
        y=y+1
    x=x+1
    y=100
print list
```

Now it doesn't give an error, but it gives an empty list as output. I tried to debug the code by inserting print statements in between. The loops appear to work fine, as 'x' and 'y' print all the values they are supposed to. However, I get an empty list as an output to the print list command and 'z' does not apparently change values and is stuck at 100000 despite me using while loops to change the values of x and y.

I am at a loss on how to proceed from here.

Comment: Stop using so many globals! Use function arguments to get inputs and use `return` to pass back outputs

Comment: You are reducing z every time by dividing it to 10.

Comment: I think you're overthinking your palindromes. My "is_palidrome" is `def isPalidrome(x): return x == int(str(x)[::-1])` Or literally, is the number the same when I cast it to a string, [reverse it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation), and cast it back to an int?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen exactly :D

Comment: It is simple to generate all products of two positive integers with three digits descending (from 999 to 100), then the first one that is a palindrome is the largest.  Testing an integer for palindromicity can be done by stringifying it which makes it to an array of chars that can be reversed with [::-1] and comparing to the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you got was probably:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment
```

This means that `z` was not defined, at least not within the `palindrome()` function. Your solution of adding the `global` keyword is technically correct. However, as others have pointed out already, use of globals makes the code hard to follow.

It's not clear to me what `palindrome()` is supposed to do. Is it supposed to check if a number is a palindrome? Generate palindrome numbers? To fix this problem, you should think about structuring your code. There are many ways to do this, of course, and with time you will find your own style.

My advice, then, is to think about how you would solve this in general. If you don't know the solution, coding won't help you. Sometimes, when solving problems like this one, I write functions without declaring their bodies. You can do this top-down or bottom-up, both work. For example:

```
def is_palindrome(n):
    """ Check if n is a palindrome number. """
    pass

def multiples_of_3_digits():
    """ Return all numbers that are the product of two 3-digit numbers ."""
    pass

def main():
    print max(n for n in multiples_of_3_digits() if is_palindrome(n))
```

This way you can focus on solving the problem, then on the actual coding. Maybe you will add helper functions or realize you can solve the problem in a more efficient way, but it's a start. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
min=100
max=999
max_palindrome = 0
for a in range(min,max + 1):
    for b in range(a + 1, max + 1):
        prod = a*b
        if prod > max_palindrome and str(prod)==(str(prod)[::-1]):
            max_palindrome = prod
print max_palindrome
```

Here we are only concerned with the maximum palindrome, and so we don’t spend any time storing other palindromes once they are known to be non-maximum. Also, the if statement first checks if the given product is larger than the maximum known palindrome before using the string cast and list slice to check whether or not the number is even a palindrome. This should speed up our code a bit since the greater than comparison will often fail, regardless of whether the product in question is a palindrome. When we run this, we get the following.

```
906609
```

Alternate Way:

I would discourage you to use the global variables because of the reasons pointed out by others. I would also like you to refer to Andre's approach as it will teach you to organize yourself. In this approach too I will be using 2 functions is_palindrome(num) [to check if the number is palindrome or not] and find_max_palindrome [to find the largest palindrome]

```
def is_palindrome(num):
    reversed = 0
    original = num

    if num < 10:
        return True
    if num % 10 == 0:
        return False

    while num >= 1:
        reversed = (reversed * 10) + (num % 10)
        num = num/10

    if original == reversed:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def find_max_palindrome():
    max_palindrome = 0
    a = 999
    b = 999
    prod = 0

    while a > 99:
        b = 999
        while b >= a:
            prod = a*b
            if prod > max_palindrome and is_palindrome(prod):
                max_palindrome = prod
            b = b -1
        a = a - 1

    return max_palindrome

print find_max_palindrome()
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted your answer without even bothering to comment. It works and you wrote a good explanation. I hope this will not discourage you from further involvement in StackOverflow, not everyone here is like that!

Comment: @AndréLaszlo  Two things.  1) The explanation was edited in later.  2) This does not answer the Overlord's question at all.  Overlord is asking for help with his code, not asking for a totally separate solution.  Being given totally separate code that solves the Euler question is akin to asking for help fixing up your car and having someone give you a new car altogether; it might help you drive to work, but you haven't learned anything.

Comment: @Alex You are right in pointing out that my solution was totally different from what he was trying to do. He is checking if a number is a palindrome by reversing the digits arithmetically, while I am testing the same thing by casting the integer as a string and using a list slice to reverse the characters. The later approach is much faster than the former and that is the reason I used it. I am going to however re-edit my answer with the alternate way soon..

Comment: @Andre I started learning programming using python last month. And thanks to mitx 6.00.1x and stackoverflow I have learnt a lot. So nothing is going to discourage me from contributing to StackOverflow :)

Comment: @Alex, I agree with both points. Personally I reserve the downvotes for incorrect or misleading answers. Trolls or spam are flagged of course. If someone provides a solution instead of leading you in the right direction, at least they made an honest effort. I also think it's nice to give feedback, especially to new users, instead of (or as a complement to) a downvote.